# App keep crushing when Instagram login is cancel

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram

This app keep crashing when Instagram login is cancel, I guess it crashing due to the response object, I am a bit confused.

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = navigationController.navigationBar;
navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:232.0 / 255.0 green:129.0 / 255.0 blue:91.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];
navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.collectionView registerClass:[THPhotoCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photo"];
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.accessToken = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"accessToken"];

if (self.accessToken == nil) {
    [SimpleAuth authorize:@"instagram" options:@{@"scope": @[@"likes"]} completion:^(NSDictionary *responseObject, NSError *error) {

        self.accessToken = responseObject[@"credentials"][@"token"];

        [userDefaults setObject:self.accessToken forKey:@"accessToken"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];

        [self refresh];
    }];
} else {
    [self refresh];
}
[self refresh];

[self refresh];
}


- (void)refresh
 {
    if (self.loading) {
        return;
    }

    self.loading = YES;

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    // You can change the hashtag here to make your very own photo browser app!
    NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/selfie/media/recent?access_token=%@&count=500", self.accessToken];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:location];
        NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        self.photos = [responseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"data"];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
            self.loading = NO;
        });
    }];
    [task resume];
}
```

Comment: try to pass error [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

Comment: Why [self refresh]; is called back-to-back 3 times? Have you enabled 'Exception Breakpoint'? When asking a questions on crashes/errors, mentioning the crash log(or at least error description) is useful for the community to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Photo Bombers";

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[THPhotoCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photo"];
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.accessToken = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"accessToken"];

    if (self.accessToken == nil) {
        [SimpleAuth authorize:@"instagram" options:@{@"scope": @[@"basic", @"comments", @"likes", @"relationships"]} completion:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {

            self.accessToken = responseObject[@"credentials"][@"token"];

            [userDefaults setObject:self.accessToken forKey:@"accessToken"];
            [userDefaults synchronize];

            [self refresh];
        }];
    } else {
        [self refresh];
    }
}
```